# Webclipse cannot find module even though angular CLI can build

Tags: angular, typescript, import, compiler-errors

I have a fairly standard project structure

```
src
|
+--app
   |
   +--components
   |  |
   |  +-component.ts
   |
   +--entities
      |
      +--entity.ts
```

In `entity.ts`, I have

```
export class Entity {
...
```

In `component.ts`, I have

```
import { Entity } from 'app/entities/entity';
```

When I run `ng build`, everything compiles fine. However, Webclipse complains that it `Cannot find module 'app/entities/entity'`.

If I change `component.ts` to instead read

```
import { Entity } from '../entities/entity';
```

it works in both Webclipse and `ng build`. However, for reasons of coding practices here at the firm, this is not a change that the architects are comfortable with, and I agree.

How can I get Webclipse to recognize this import? Is there, say, a way to configure the import root for the Webclipse TS compiler?

Comment: Looks like one of your tools is missing the base URL

Comment: @AluanHaddad Aaaand it was as simple as that. My tsconfig.json had a baseUrl "". I changed it to "." and everything works... :| Turn your comment into an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: I didn't know which URL you're missing, typescript , webpack, angular-cli, or something else period you figured it out so I would suggest you post your solution as an answer to question and I will vote for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, things were simpler than expected. My `tsconfig.json` started as follows:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "",
```

I changed the last line to read

```
    "baseUrl": ".",
```

and everything now works. Thanks to Aluan Haddad, as his comment sent me in the right direction.